# Nginx Proxy Manager and html page for proxy host

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

The Nginx Proxy Manager works itself Ok. I maintain a java app which starts from IDE on *my_laptop_local_ip:port*. This app has a develop branch (using cloud server) there modifications could be tested before launch. Sometimes I need to expose to the web, then I work on *feature/branch*. To show others not finished work. This is rear. Can I add to reverse-proxy configuration *not_launched.html page* then the app is not running locally?